Nested interface definition in Angular
I have an interface with a complex type as a member like this.
export interface Activity {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  segment: Segment;
}

export interface Segment {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}

I'm used to C# and nested classes so somewhere in my spine I feel that this might be improved so that the structure of the segment is inside the activity. I'm not sure what it's called so I failed finding/recognized adequate examples.
Is t even possible in TypeScript/Angular? I'm not sure I've even seen an import to such a nested type ever-ever. In case it's possible, what are the disadvantages/caveats (except the obvious complexity of the interfaces)? In case it's not a feasible choice relying on interfaces, are classes or types something that would be?
Proof of effort.

This on presents a structure without the names of the internal entity.
This one has corresponding structure but no answer.
This one turned out to be totally unrelated despite the title.
This one is weirdly downvoted for unclear reason.
This one touches the right spots but lack an apparent answer to my issue.
This one is way overkill and I still can't recognize my particular need.


sorry, what is the problem? "so that the structure of the segment is inside the activity". so export interface Activity {
id: string;
name: string;
segment: {
id: string;
name: string;
}
}
?

erm, ok I think I understand the question. and to answer there are no nested classes or interfaces in js/ts.

@Omkar76 Thanks for the reply. As per your suggestion, you declare a field segment and specify its type. What if I need to refer to it (e.g. by creating an object and forcing it to be an instance of a segment by: {} as Segment or {} as Activity.Segment? Or am I only allowed to {} as Activity and can't instantiate the individual parts (here: the segment) beforehand?

In TS you can use Indexed Access Types to refer to inner types. In your case: Activity['segment'] is the same as Segment.  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html

See this devworkbench link. Personally I'd think this is worse than just exporting the Segment interface in the first place, since you're just moving the work of giving it a named type from the exporting file to the importing file. Does this fully address the question? If so someone (@MatthieuRiegler maybe) could write an answer; if not, what's missing?

@jcalz I interpret the comments as "it's not possible precisely as I described" but also "it's possible in a way but not recommended". In such case, nothing more needs to be added. Should we close the question or just post the trivial answer of "nope!"?

You can use namespace for that:
export interface Activity {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  segment: Activity.Segment;
}

export namespace Activity {
  export interface Segment {
    id: string;
    name: string;
  }
}

